# How can I add the rows and copy the value?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

The table looks like

| Person | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| p_key | e_key |
|  | e_name |

I want to add the value of e_name into Person.

I added the p_name column to Person table by using
"ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD P_NAME CHAR(25)"

but I don't know how to put the values into them. p_name is all empty.

How can I copy the value from e_name to p_name in Person.
Or is there any other way to copy the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `merge` would do, if matching columns are `p_key` and `e_key`.

```
merge into person p
  using employee e
  on (e.e_key = p.p_key)
  when matched then update set
    p.p_name = e.e_name;
```

---

BTW, don't use `char` datatype, it'll right-pad all values with spaces up to full column length. Use `varchar2` instead.