# I cannot select the things after I add the column to the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I use

```
"ALTER TABLE LINEITEM ADD(L_NATIONNAME VARCHAR(25))"
```

and add the column l_nationname to lineitem.

Next I used

```
UPDATE LINEITEM
SET L_NATOINNAME = (SELECT N_NAME
                    FROM NATION
                    WHERE L_KEY = N_KEY);
```

To copy the name data from 'NATION' to 'LINEITEM'

when I query

```
"SELECT * 
FROM LINEITEM;"
```

Then I can check that the column is well copied but I cannot obtain any values by using

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_NATIONNAME = 'SOMETHING';
```

even though the data is there, I cannot select with where clauses.
Should I do something further after adding and updating column for selection?
If not, what is the prob here?

Comment: What is the data type of `NATION.N_NAME`? If it is `CHAR(25)` then it will blank-padded, so you could `trim()` the value as you copy it across, or update the value after copying. (Both should probably be `VARCHAR2(25)`, not `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`).

Comment: Too bad you don't listen to advice you were given in your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240268/how-can-i-add-the-rows-and-copy-the-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `NATION.N_NAME` is defined as a `CHAR` column - presumably `CHAR(25)`.

That means the values in it will be blank-padded to that length, and when you copy them to the `LINEITEM.L_NATIONNAME` column that padding will be preserved - so you will have `'SOMETHING                '` (with 16 spaces to make it up to 25 characters), not `'SOMETHING'`.

You *could* just include the spaces when you search:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_NATIONNAME = 'SOMETHING                ';
```

or with slightly less scope for mistakes:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_NATIONNAME = RPAD('SOMETHING', 25, ' ');
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_NATIONNAME = CAST('SOMETHING' AS CHAR(25));
```

Or you could trim the spaces from the table value - though applying a function like this would prevent a normal index on that column being used, if you had one, so it's generally a bad idea:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE RTRIM(L_NATIONNAME) = 'SOMETHING';
```

But it would be better to avoid the issue by trimming the values as they are copied:

```
UPDATE LINEITEM
SET L_NATIONNAME = (SELECT RTRIM(N_NAME)
                    FROM NATION
                    WHERE L_KEY = N_KEY);
```

Really you would be better of only ever using the `VARCHAR2` data type, not `CHAR` (or `VARCHAR`, as you have in `LINEITEM`). There is an argument for having single-character values like flags as `CHAR(1)`, but opinions differ; or perhaps for fixed-length values; but for anything longer than one character there are unlikely to be any real benefits of using `CHAR` over `VARCHAR2`.

If you are able to redefine your tables with `VARCHAR2` instead of `CHAR` then you will find the string values easier to work with.

Read more in the documentation about [`CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-85E0A0DD-9E90-4AE1-9AD5-93C89FDCFC49), [`VARCHAR2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0DC7FFAA-F03F-4448-8487-F2592496A510), why you should not use [`VARCHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E) (though that has been 'scheduled to be redefined' for as long as I can remember - several decades at least), and [comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C__GUID-6F832501-CBAF-4F38-B737-1A4BFEEC7C07).